# How do you unit test a PlayN project?

Tags: maven, junit, playn

I have managed to get basic unit testing working, however when I add a unit test to project-java I get an error of class not found, looking into it it seems when compiling the testing classes, it dosn't copy the main classes from the project-core, does anyone have any idea how to fix this in maven?

Edit:
To make things more clear, I do know where to place the tests, I have placed in project-java/src/tests However What I mean is it doesnt invlude the clases from project-core/src

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better approach is to add your tests to `core/src/test/java` and then add a `test` dependency on `playn-java` to your `core/pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.googlecode.playn</groupId>
  <artifactId>playn-java</artifactId>
  <version>${playn.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thankyou, if I hadn't allready gone a different route, that would probably have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store all yours tests not in src/main, but in src/test.

I used JUnit with this guide: [Using Junit](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html)

Comment: I do store my tests in the src/test the problem is when testing in maven it Doesn't copy the appropriate classes from core project to java project like it does when running. I know how to use Junit, the trouble is maven does not seem to understand when using the subprojects, to copy the appropriate classes.

Comment: If you read the guide, it is not about "How to use JUnit", but "How to use JUnit with Maven".

Comment: Which is again, something I know, and the guide has said nothing new, I already KNEW how to use it with maven, what I dont know is how to make it react properly with subprojects, as it is clearly not doing so with the playn project.

Comment: Easy mistake to make when you have multiple windows open of similar Questions, it was just a bit of a wtf moment for myself.

Answer (score 0):

I went a different route with this in the end, and actually made a playn-testframework.
a simple playn- project that acted like playn-java etc, but would not render to screen, and had extra callbacks for the tests to use, such as to simulate mouse/keyboard events.